# How to solve a stochastic integral in python

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-integrals, python

I need to implement (solve) a stochastic integral in python. I have observations of a time series X, assumed to behave like Brownian motion with drift,
which changes from zero to a known constant V at some time Tc which is given by the smallest time t for which  :

$ \int_0^t e^{a(Xt-Xs)+b(t-s)}ds  > K $

for some known constants a,b and K

How can this be solved on paper? It is confusing that the integral is with respect to ds and not dW. While Xs is assumed to be a BM with change of drift at t, all I have are some observations. Also, is there a preferred way of implementing equations like these programatically? Any resources (maybe for numerical estimation etc) would be great.

Comment: In that integral, $X_t$ is simply a continuous function. The usual integration methods apply, however, since there is no differentiability the usual error estimates do not apply, all methods have error order $1$ for stochastic processes.

Comment: Hi, yes so Xt can be taken out of the integral, but Xs cannot. It follows a SDE as I mentioned above.

Comment: I mean $t\mapsto X_t$ as function. It is, as solution of an SDE, (almost surely) continuous. But most likely not even Lipschitz. That $X$ follows a SDE does not matter for the question of evaluating this integral from a time series.

Comment: LutzL is saying that you can generate a trajectory of $X_t$ in the usual way (e.g. Euler-Maruyama) and then plug it into any standard routine for computing integrals like the rectangle rule. The annoying thing is that the solutions to an SDE are so irregular that the higher order methods like the trapezoidal rule or Simpson rule fail to be higher order.

Comment: Ok, what I am also struggling to understand is that whether my actual observations of Xs influence the solution. To me it appears not if I say all the other variables in the equation are known and also the variables describing the dynamics of X ($dX= V*(I(t>Tc)) dt +sdW$) are assumed known. The only way the solution changes would be if the variables describing X's behavior change when the sample X changes. Does this sound right?

Comment: Your values of $X$ change the solution, of course. This is like the difference between $\int_0^t e^{a(t-s)+b(t-s)} ds$ and $\int_0^t e^{a(2t-2s)+b(t-s)} ds$; these are clearly different.

Comment: Ok this might sound extremely dumb, but I am not sure what role would simulating _**Xt**_ play when I already have observations of _Xt_. I guess this is the primary confusion for me as all the theory relating to Stochastic integrals seems to mention simulation but I already have a sample (discrete ofcourse). I am not able to figure out how I can use the equation mentioned above to find the relevant t.

Comment: Should I just replace the above equation with a summation? 

$\sum_{s=0}^t (e^{a(Xt−Xs)+b(t−s)} )$ and see at which _**t**_ this becomes >K?

Comment: You need to multiply by some $\Delta t$ and add up terms up to $t=n \Delta t$. But otherwise yes that's right. Moreover you won't be able to do any better because of the irregularity of the trajectories of $X_t$. Simulation is where you would get such a sample; I'm not sure I understand where the stochasticity even is when you say you already have a fixed sample that you are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Ian. Yes I was taking Δt =1 here. So the thing is that I have a time series of data and I am trying to apply the above theory to estimate the point (time) where the drift changed from zero to some known value V. Eventually, I will apply this to an online framework where I will repeatedly get many observations samples of Xt. So that's where the stochasticity will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the integral doesn't contain the dW term, I am not sure if it should even be called a stochastic integral. Also, itegrals of stochastic functions (Xt here) require simulations to solve them as the integral isn't deterministic. In this case, however, I already have observations of Xt. So I think the way to implement this procedure/equation would be simply to replace the above integral with a summation (using $\Delta t=1$)

$\sum_0^t(e^{a(Xt−Xs)+b(t−s))}$, plug in the observed values of X0...Xt for various values of t and see for which t this becomes >K